# Grep Or Regex to transform css

Tags: html, css, regex, grep, stylesheet

I have several stylesheets with hundreds of lines of code. The stylesheets are conflicting with other stylesheets and I want to isolate there specificity to a single div. I don't want to use an iframe and I tried changing the precedence of the stylsheets in the head element.

Is there a grep or regex command that I can run to insert this string `#isolated-div` as the first selector in every line of all the specified stylsheets? That way, every style applied to an element will have to be an element that is a child of the div.

Nevermind top order elements like body or iframe.

Comment: What does your stylesheet look like?

Comment: http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap.min.css

But.. there are like several. I mean.. its css. So the format is going to be the same no matter what. Except for the ones that are minified. I can formt those with line breaks after every selector property pair.

Comment: Have you looked at less CSS? It enhances CSS by adding the capability to do clever things such as nesting selectors in other selectors. In this case it would mean that rather than changing every rule you could just wrap the whole stylessheet in a #isolated-div selector. There are various implementations of it for both clientside use and server side (I've been very happy with dotLess for .NET).

Comment: Wow I had no idea about that. Thank you so much Chris!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is an AWK solution OK?

```
awk -F'{' '{split($1, sel, ","); 
            for(i in sel) {if (i>1) printf(","); printf("#isolated-div %s", sel[i]); }
            printf("{%s\n", $2) }' filename.min.css > filename.new.min.css
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the stylesheets look, but I will give it a go. Something as simple as this *could* work but is by no means perfect: http://regex101.com/r/gI1hV0

`/^[^{}]+{/gm`

But I can't guarantee it'll work every time.